# Async / await code not called in useEffect function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, async-await

I can't figure out why the await function setDoc is not completed in my example below when I launch my react native app for the first time.

When I launch it a second time however, it works well.

Can you help me?

```
useEffect(() => {

    registerForPushNotificationsAsync().then(async token => {
      
      // The following gets called
      console.log("Before await")

      // The following does not complete when I first launch the app.
      await setDoc(doc(db, "devices", token), { test: "test" })
        .then(x => {
          // The following does not get called
          console.log('Sucess')
          
        })
        .catch(error => {
          // The following does not get called
          console.log('Error')
        })

      // The following does not get called
      console.log("After await")
    });

    return () => {};
  }, []);
```

with registerForPushNotificationsAsync defined outside useEffect as:

```
async function registerForPushNotificationsAsync() {
  ...
  return token;
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Eithere use `async-await` or `.then`

Comment: @NullPointerException, I've just tried: removing .then() and .error() does not solve my problem.

Comment: Can you show your setDoc and doc methods?

Comment: These are the setDoc and doc methods from firebase: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#set_a_document

Comment: Might need to see your code in the registerForPushNotificationsAsync
because the code you have posted doesn't explain the behaviour you are seeing

Answer (score 1):

Try moving the async function outside of the useEffect function:

```js
const someAsyncFunc = async () => {
    console.log("Before await")
    try {
        const token = await registerForPushNotificationsAsync();
        await setDoc(doc(db, "devices", token), { test: "test" })
        console.log('Success')
    } catch (error) {
        /// do error handling
        console.log(error);
    }
    console.log("After await")
}

useEffect(() => {
  someAsyncFunc();
}, []);
```

Comment: I've just tried your solution, unfortunately it does not change the problem, the setDoc function does not complete.

Comment: I think your setDoc function does not work properly. Can you try debugging it? I would recommend to call the setDoc function with a button and add debug logs. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If there a reason why you want to use await there ?

Otherwise you should try to do this using only `.then` and syncronious code :

```
useEffect(() => {

    return registerForPushNotificationsAsync().then(async token => {
    
    // The following gets called
    console.log("Before await")

    // The following does not complete when I first launch the app.
    return setDoc(doc(db, "devices", token), { test: "test" })
        .then(x => {
        // The following does not get called
        console.log('Sucess')
        
        })
        .then(() => {
            // The following does not get called
            console.log("After await")
            return () => {};
        })
        .catch(error => {
        // The following does not get called
        console.log('Error')
        })
    });
}, []);
```

Comment: It does not work either, thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

use `async await` as follows.

```
useEffect(() => {
  registerForPushNotificationsAsync().then(async (token) => {
    // The following gets called
    console.log('Before await');

    try {
      await setDoc(doc(db, 'devices', token), { test: 'test' });
      console.log('Sucess');
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('Error');
    }

    // The following does not get called
    console.log('After await');
  });

  return () => {};
}, []);
```

Comment: Similar to the previous answer : I've just tried your solution, unfortunately it does not change the problem, the setDoc function does not complete.